# How do I create a timeseries sliding window tensorflow dataset where some features have different batch sizes than others?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Currently I am able to create a timeseries sliding window batched dataset that contains ordered 'feature sets' like 'inputs', 'targets', 'benchmarks', etc. Originally I had developed my model and dataset wherein the targets would be of the same batch size as all other inputs, however that has proven to be detrimental to tuning the input batch size and also won't be helpful when it comes time to run this on live data where I only care to produce a single sample output of the shape `(1, horizon, targets)` or perhaps just `(horizon, targets)` given an input dataset of `(samples, horizon, features)`.

As an overview, I want to take `N` historical samples of `horizon` length `features` at time `T`, run them through the model and output a single sample of `horizon` length `targets`; repeat until the dataset is run through in its entirety.

Assuming a pandas DataFrame of length `Z`, all resulting Datasets should have a length of `Z - horizon`. The 'targets' Dataset should have a batch size of 1, and the 'inputs' Dataset should have a batch size of `batch_size`.

---

Here's a stripped down snippet of what I currently use in order to generate a standard batch size for all feature sets:

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

horizon = 5
batch_size = 10
columns = {
    "inputs": ["input_1", "input_2"],
    "targets": ["target_1"],
}
batch_options = {
    "drop_remainder": True,
    "deterministic": True,
}

d = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'input_1': d, 'input_2': d, 'target_1': d})

slices = tuple(df[x].astype("float32") for x in columns.values())
data = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(slices)
    .window(horizon, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    .flat_map(
        lambda *c: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
            tuple(
                col.batch(horizon, **batch_options)
                for col in c
            )
        )
    )
    .batch(
        batch_size,
        **batch_options,
    )
)
```

Comment: In the above example, for 1st batch- inputs are [[[ 0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.]
  [ 2.  2.]
  [ 3.  3.]
  [ 4.  4.]], and targets are [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]. Do you want the target to be just [0]?

Comment: I want to output a single sequence of N features (1, horizon, features); in this example: [[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]]

Comment: this is target right?. You need (batch,time,horizon,features) for inputs and (batch, 1, horizon, features) for labels?

Comment: Inputs: (batch, horizon, features); Labels: (1, horizon, features)

Comment: labels need to skip (batch-1) for the second batch?

Comment: There should be no skipping of timesteps; all timesteps should be processed sequentially, it's just that the inputs should have more historical samples from which to draw; the output should only have 1 sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create two sliding windowed dataset and zip them.

```
inputs = df[['input_1', 'input_1']].to_numpy()
labels = df['target_1'].to_numpy()


window_size = 10
stride =1
data1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs).window(window_size, shift=stride, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(window_size))
data2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs).window(1, shift=stride, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(1))
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((data1, data2))
```